# Light passing through paper layers. How?

Tags: materials

I'm trying to simulate some layers of paper being backlit so they create an effect similar to this:

[image]

This image I made in 3Ds Max using the 2sidedMaterial from Vray, but I'm migrating to Blender, and was wondering if there is any way to achieve this effect.

I want the light to go through all layers, losing intensity.

I'm trying to use Translucency with Diffuse, but the light seems to stop on the first layer of paper, and the rest seems to be just light bounced on the material.

If I try to use Transparent Material, the paper becomes very transparent and I can see the previous layers, creating a strange effect.

In short, I do not know exactly where to go to set this material up in the right way, so if anyone knows how to tell me a way, I'd be grateful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that using a translucent shader should work for this. [image]

Just make sure in your render tab you have your lights paths set high enough to go through all the planes. [image]