# How do I emit light from within an object using a point light (Chinese Lantern)

Tags: mesh, texturing, shaders, lighting, volumetrics

[image: paper lantern]

I scaled up an Icosphere and want to create the effect of a very big Chinese lantern, but irrespective of the material. I can't seem to get the light to emit from within the object. It just keeps getting trapped if that makes sense so I don't know wether or not there are certain volume settings I need to toggle to allow light to pass through or what.

Comment: What is your current shader setup, render result? Show us some reference of desired result. You can share simplified blend file so we can check it. https://blend-exchange.com/ ... something like this https://imgur.com/OuEhVKs ? Please extend your question. This site is meant to be source of knowledge, so others can learn from you too ... it is helpful also for you to learn by identifying your current issue.

Comment: Sorry for not adding my blend file as reference because like I said, I only have a scaled up sphere but am unsure on how to achieve the look created in my attached reference image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Light passing through paper (Chinese Lantern)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247315/light-passing-through-paper-chinese-lantern)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210228  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158718  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292447  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130391  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69406 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247759  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44253
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886

Answer (score 7):

I think **Translucent BSDF** shader is key of this material so check [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24886/2214).

Or you can use *Principled BSDF* shader where especially **Transmission** parameter set to 1 will do the job.

[image]
[image]

With *Extra Curve* addon you can add *Spiral > Shere* for lantern wire. Also care about *Point* light's *Power* and *Radius*, it affects final result.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could fake it with a *Layer Weight* that you use as factor between 2 Emission shaders:

[image]